# Change port parameters used by a database in Docker without updating the image?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to change the database port from the `postgres` docker image. The following properly opens the port 5000 but does not do the first step of telling postgres to start on a non-default port :

```
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 --env POSTGRES_DB=mydb --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypw --env POSTGRES_USER=myuser my.company.repo/postgres:11-alpine
```

Do I need to create my own image that does

```
from my.company.repo/postgres:11-alpine
# some command to change the pg port to 5000
```

Is there another way to simply change the postgres port?

**Update**  Thinking on this.. i'm guessing the way to do it is to ensure the docker image is expecting POSTGRES_PORT as an environment variable. If not the image has to be changed..

Comment: aha ya that's what I wanted. go ahead and make that an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of changing the port that PostgreSQL uses you can just map the host port you want to use to the default port in the container (`5432`)

```
docker run -p 5000:5432 ...
```